# Filemaker Pro 14 History tables

Tags: filemaker

With a few solutions Ive worked with I've created temp table's or history tables. Normally I script it to take a handful of fields needed from a main table and copy it over to the other table by

Setting a variable then setting field to the variable for each field in the new table / new record.

I have a situation now, where Im building a history table that needs to copy the current record as is. A snapshot where all fields from that instance of the record are copied to the history table.

Rather then setting a variable then set field to the variable, Id like to get some input on a quicker way to get this done where I can do this on a record level and not type out field by field to get it done. Also if fields are added to both tables then I have to make sure my script gets updated.

Ill keep hunting around.. appreciate any help.
-Rich

Comment: In order to keep working, very unclean way that I found works for now. Im exporting the current record to xlsx file, then importing it to the history table as a new record. Now in my portal I can see the snapshot of the record and open it in my history form. Def not my vision as I would like to keep it all in FMP, but it works as I want it.

Comment: You can import directly from one table to another, if you want. But I am not sure what exactly is your purpose here. What is the intended use of these "snapshots"?

Comment: Ill have to research more, just found a few examples but people are pushing data out just as I am above in files. Do you have a sample of copying a record from 1 table to another including all fields and setting some fields? I copy the snapshot per events that happen to the record. The user may need to go back to look at a full instance of that record later. SO I stamp the snapshot with a HistoryTypeCode and show in a portal. If they need to look at a snapshot they select portal record with a OpenPopup that has a copy of the main form but of the snapshot.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit, why you need an exact copy of current records?  That sounds more like a backup, which is a builtin function of FM Server.

Comment: "*people are pushing data out just as I am*' I have posted an answer, but I need to say that I have not yet seen a case where this would be required.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks...

Comment: As far as needing a exact copy of current record, its only a exact copy for certain actions and then the current record can have changes made. Its a very long winded explanation. This is a pretty rare case scenario thou but if your interested in hearing about it I would be happy to email. thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you have a sample of copying a record from 1 table to another
>   including all fields and setting some fields?

As I suggested in comments, use the `Import Records[]` script step, and select the same file as the source.  If you choose `Arrange by: [ matching names ]` in the Import Field Mapping dialog, it will automatically map all source fields to their similarly named counterparts.

Note that you must establish a found set in the source table before importing.

For "setting some fields", you can define auto-enter options and activate them during the import, or run `Replace Field Contents[]` immediately after the import.